# How to migrate repositories from Perforce to GitHub using git p4 when the source repository path contains spaces

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

We are moving from Perfoce to GitHub and we are using git-p4 to migrate our solutions with full history.  Some of the solutions however, have spaces in their source paths.

e.g. //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/Proposal12345

Note the space between JOE and SOAP.

No matter what we've tried, we can't get the migration to succeed.

Here are the combinations we've tried with the related output

```
git p4 clone //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/Proposal12345@all
Importing from //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE into SOAP/CR-13016@all
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/CommandLineTools/temp/SOAP/CR-13016@all/.git/
Doing initial import of //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
p4 returned an error: //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/...#head - no such file(s).

fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
      marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
      atoms:              0
Memory total:          2399 KiB
       pools:          2048 KiB
     objects:           351 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 35184372088832
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
git p4 clone //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE\ SOAP/Proposal12345@all
Importing from //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/ into SOAP/CR-13016@all
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/CommandLineTools/temp/SOAP/CR-13016@all/.git/
Doing initial import of //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
p4 returned an error: //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/...#head - no such file(s).

fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
      marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
      atoms:              0
Memory total:          2399 KiB
       pools:          2048 KiB
     objects:           351 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 35184372088832
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
git p4 clone "//Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/Proposal12345@all"
Importing from //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/CR-13016@all into CR-13016
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/CommandLineTools/temp/CR-13016/.git/
Command failed: p4 -d "C:\CommandLineTools\temp\CR-13016" changes //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/CR-13016/...
fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
      marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
      atoms:              0
Memory total:          2399 KiB
       pools:          2048 KiB
     objects:           351 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 35184372088832
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
git p4 clone "//Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE\ SOAP/Proposal12345@all"
Importing from //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/ SOAP/CR-13016@all into CR-13016
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/CommandLineTools/temp/CR-13016/.git/
Command failed: p4 -d "C:\CommandLineTools\temp\CR-13016" changes //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE/ SOAP/CR-13016/...
fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:       5000
Total objects:            0 (         0 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      trees  :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      commits:            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           0 (         0 loads     )
      marks:           1024 (         0 unique    )
      atoms:              0
Memory total:          2399 KiB
       pools:          2048 KiB
     objects:           351 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =      65536
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 35184372088832
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =          0
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =          0
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          0 /          0
pack_report: pack_mapped              =          0 /          0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely what the problem is, I'd expect the 3rd alternative to work.

Maybe try doing it on Linux?

Also maybe try running `p4 -d "C:\CommandLineTools\temp\CR-13016" changes //Development/Custom/Projects/API1/JOE SOAP/CR-13016/...` directly and see what fails?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  when running the command directly, I get the list of changes on the project.

Comment: The above obviously excludes the git repo creation step.  I've updated the git-p4 python script to support spaces, but during the git-p4-dump process I get an error from fast-import: fatal: Empty path component found in input